# magic example using search and/or regex

Tags: files, regular-expression, file-types

I am trying to have the `file` command detect some Windows text files that were never meant to be classified by file... The best choice seems to use regex to match the line content, but I cannot find a single example of its use (the commonality of the keywords 'file', 'magic', and 'regex' does not help in a google-centric world). The man page does not help.

Furthermore, I cannot get the ^ $ to work.

Both files start with

```
Project Units: <stuff>
Units & Scale - <stuff>
<blank line>
```

Next line is a header that starts
4a) Object point ID,Photo #,
4b) Id,Name,

My attempt at a magic rules for this is:

```
0  string Project\040Units:
>2 regex ^Object\040point\040ID,Photo\040#, PhotoModeler 2D export table

0  string Project\040Units:
>2 regex ^Id,Name, PhotoModeler 3D export table
```

i.e. match 'Project Units:' on the first line, then do a regex attempt to maximum 2+1 lines. Anchor regex to beginning of line for speed.

This is on Ubuntu 14.04, file-5.14.

Example of file type 1 (first 10 lines only):

```
Project Units: meters
Units & Scale - Active, Translate - Active, Rotate - Active

Object Point ID,Photo #,X (pixels),Y (pixels),Residual X,Residual Y,Residual Vector,Mark Type,Layer,Material,Tagged
2,1,1429.187065,1456.427823,-0.164541,0.182824,0.245964,LSM Circular,Default,White, 
2,2,666.583514,1126.807078,-0.168174,0.109780,0.200833,LSM Circular,Default,White, 
2,3,716.264669,1196.788962,0.152059,0.082258,0.172882,LSM Circular,Default,White, 
2,4,674.145595,442.969428,0.119315,-0.050084,0.129401,LSM Circular,Default,White, 
2,5,330.056929,836.292587,0.048372,-0.022235,0.053238,LSM Circular,Default,White, 
2,6,1147.101715,39.253316,0.475434,-0.189514,0.511814,LSM Circular,Default,White,
```

Example of file type 2 (first 10 lines only):

```
Project Units: meters
Units & Scale - Active, Translate - Active, Rotate - Active

Id,Name,Photos (used),X (project units),Y (project units),Z (project units),X Precision,Y Precision,Z Precision,Precision Vector Length,Tightness (percent),Tightness (project units),Angle (deg.),Control Name,RMS Residual (pixels),Largest Residual (pixels),Photo Largest Residual,Material,Layer,Tagged,Type,Use In Processing,Frozen,#Constraints,Target Code,Target Bits,Ref. Check Tag,Photos (marked),Color (R),Color (G),Color (B)
2," ","1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.285721,1.143037,-0.000990,0.000044,0.000043,0.000075,0.000097,0.037511,0.000682,85.604862, ,0.261467,0.511814,6,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
3," ","1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.428622,1.143108,-0.000230,0.000044,0.000042,0.000074,0.000096,0.033814,0.000615,86.326354, ,0.222883,0.475602,6,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
4," ","1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.142979,1.143124,-0.000840,0.000045,0.000044,0.000078,0.000100,0.030045,0.000546,84.468461, ,0.239445,0.374918,16,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
5," ","1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.571353,1.143164,0.000784,0.000044,0.000042,0.000074,0.000096,0.027194,0.000494,86.593419, ,0.213540,0.430629,6,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
6," ","1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.000141,1.143101,-0.000885,0.000046,0.000045,0.000081,0.000103,0.035513,0.000646,82.937166, ,0.291437,0.465014,16,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
7," ","1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",0.714058,1.143134,0.000247,0.000044,0.000043,0.000075,0.000097,0.030057,0.000547,86.326626, ,0.221009,0.426056,6,White,Default, ,Regular,yes,no,0,n/a,n/a, ,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",255,255,255
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include an example of the files you need to identify.

Comment: The caret needs to be escaped: `\^` . See eg. the [make](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/make) tests.

Comment: @terdon: Added first 10 lines of example files. Solution was to escape the caret as posted below. :)

Comment: Oh, cool, both an edit *and* an answer, thanks! It would be great if you remember to come back and accept the answer once the system lets you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [file(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) manpage only tells you how to run the command.  For a description of the magic patterns, see [magic(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic).  However, the section on `regex` isn't especially detailed.  A wide range of examples of its use can be found in the pattern files that come with it:  https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir

Your main problem was that the caret needs escaping: `\^` for beginning-of-line, `\\^` for a literal `^`.  I haven't worked out what special meaning the unescaped `^` has.  Spaces can also be escaped, making the pattern slightly more readable.

You intend to restrict the match to a narrow line range.  `regex` takes a `/<length>` option (after the word `regex`, not after the pattern), so that places a limit on where the search *ends*.  If the length is followed by an `l`, it means lines instead of bytes. In my tests, `/1l` can only match an empty line -- a non-empty line, even when using the exact start offset, requires at least `/2l`.

For the *start* of the search, `offset` is interpreted as a byte count, even with `regex`.  (Pre-version 5.19, the documentation suggests that it is interpreted as a "line count", but that statement was [removed](https://github.com/file/file/commit/5645c4f76cea64a85b26bc414d313cf78fc4255d) with no matching code change, so I doubt that it was accurate even before then.)  You could use offset `&0` to start the search from the end of the previous match, but that won't make a lot of difference when the previous match ended in the middle of the first line.

Furthermore, "beginning of line" also matches "beginning of search range" (ie. from `offset`), regardless of whether that was the start of a line in the file.

So to match things more strictly, you could use a full-line regexp on every line, and use offset `&1` on the next match, to skip the previous newline, and be in the right place for the `\^` to work as expected.  This may be overkill for identifying your custom file types.

Finally, you don't need to repeat the common parts.  The level of `>` indentation means that a pattern should be tried when previous patterns at the same level failed.

Joining that all together:

```
0       regex/2l        \^Project\ Units:.*$
>&1     regex/2l        \^Units\ &\ Scale.*$
>>&1    regex/1l        \^$
>>>&1   regex/2l        \^Object\ Point\ ID     Photo Modeler 2D export table   
>>>&1   regex/2l        \^Id,Name,Photos        Photo Modeler 3D export table
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution was due to @JigglyNaga - escape the caret. Snippet below is now part of my .magic file.

```
0   string  Project\040Units:
>2  regex   \^Id,  PhotoModeler 3D export table

0   string  Project\040Units:
>2  regex   \^Object\040Point\040ID,  PhotoModeler 2D export table
```