# how can I read a number with file (magic)?

Tags: file-command, file-types

I would like to write the format of a drawing with "file drawing"

Files start like:

```
CAD
A1 
mm
```

(Blank after A1)

or:

```
CAD
A00
m
```

(Blank after "m")

I tried somethings like in the file magic:

```
0      string  CAD\n     CAD-Drawing
>&0    regex   ^A[0-9]+  Format=[%s]
>>&0   search  \n
>>>&0  regex   ^[a-z]+   Units=[%s]
```

but with no luck!
Is there any way to solve this problem?
I would prefer to get no blanks.

That means not just:

```
0     string  CAD\n  CAD-Drawing
>&0   string  x      Format=[%s]
>>&0  string  x      Units=[%s]
```

which results in ... Format=[A1 ] ... or ... Units=[m ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexes in `man magic` are not extensively detailed.  But have a look at this [brilliant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291461/172635) by JigglyNaga.

For a start you need to escape several characters in regexes in magic files: `^`, `+` and spaces are examples.  Here are two ways of making your magic file work for the files you describe:

```
0      string  CAD\n       CAD-Drawing
>&0    regex   \^A[0-9]\+  Format=[%s]
>>&0   search  \n
>>>&0  regex   \^[a-z]\+   Units=[%s]
```

This ignores the spaces, and therefore will print the following:

```
$ file -m mmm file[12].cad 
file1.cad: CAD-Drawing Format=[A1] Units=[mm]
file2.cad: CAD-Drawing Format=[A00] Units=[m]
```

A better way (in my humble opinion) is to keep spaces in the *Version* and *Units* strings:

```
0      string  CAD\n         CAD-Drawing
>&0    regex   \^A[0-9\ ]\+  Format=[%s]
>>&0   search  \n
>>>&0  regex   \^[a-z\ ]\+   Units=[%s]
```

(Note that I needed to escape the spaces even that they're inside character groups).

This prints the following:

```
$ file -m mmm file[12].cad 
file1.cad: CAD-Drawing Format=[A1 ] Units=[mm]
file2.cad: CAD-Drawing Format=[A00] Units=[m ]
```

References:

- [magic example using search and/or regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291334/magic-example-using-search-and-or-regex)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and competent answer.
My real problem was an old SuSE (10.1) version, which does not work with regex in magic file.
I just tried on SuSE 12.1 (also old) and it works.